# How can i use asgi completely in django?

Tags: django, asgi

I'm new to django. After searching here and their i found asgi enable performance boost over django wsgi based view. So that i want to completely switch to asgi view but i din't found any guides regarding to it so that i can i implement it in views(function and class) and django orm.

And also I'm pretty much unsure about how it works.

If this question make no any sense, then sorry for that and help me regarding to asgi which is new features in django3. How it is different from django channel.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/asgi/

Answer (score 1):

ASGI will indeed boost the performance but reading your post gives me the sense that you don't really need that performance.

Currently you can check which things are async in the django docs and you can check the roadmap as well. As of now I think Django already has async views but I am unsure of the ORM. If you really need performance of that type, you should turn to other frameworks like **FastAPI**.

As for django-channels and django3 you can read the discussion here: https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1416